# android.widget.filter displaying different results in my custom base adapter

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my filter method it didnt display the filter result in my listview
here is my code:

```
    public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            //
            final FilterResults searchResults = new FilterResults();

            final ArrayList<music> resulta = new ArrayList<music>();
            //  
            if (_musicList == null)
                _musicList = musicList; 
            //
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (_musicList != null && _musicList.size() > 0) {
                    for (final music _music : _musicList) {
                        //
                        Log.d("constraint", constraint.toString() + " " + _music.getTitle().toString());

                        if (_music.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())){
                            Log.d("add items", _music.getTitle());
                            resulta.add(_music);
                        }   
                    }
                    //
                    for (music music : resulta) {
                        Log.d("result item", music.getTitle());
                    }
                    searchResults.values = resulta;
                }
            }
            else{
                searchResults.values = musicList;
            }
            return searchResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            //
            Log.d("final result", results.values.toString());
            //
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            //
            musicList = (ArrayList<music>) results.values;
            //
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

}
```

I check the items being filter and its correct but
It display the wrong items it just display the last two items in the listview instead of the filter items

here is the code in my textview:

```
    @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {



                musicListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
```

what am i doing wrong? I really need some help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is right, the problem is my getView method i just modify it now and it works perfectly fine now.... here is my entire code

```
public static final int SEARCH_TITLE = 12;
public static final int SEARCH_ARTIST = 23;
public static final int SEARCH_KARAOKENUMBER = 34;

    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    songListWidgetHolder viewHolder = null;
    String title;
    String artist;

    if (convertView == null) {
        //
        if (musicList != null && musicList.size() > 0) {

            // Log.d("size", String.valueOf(musicList.size()));

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) Act
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            final String _title = musicList.get(position).getTitle();

            title = AppUtils.ShortText(_title, 7);

            final String _artist = musicList.get(position).getArtist();

            artist = AppUtils.ShortText(_artist, 5);

            switch (sortkey) {
            case SORT_ARTIST_DESC:
            case SORT_ARTIST_ASC:

                viewHolder = new songListWidgetHolder();
                //
                viewHolder.ArtistTV = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.artisttx);
                viewHolder.ArtistTV = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.artisttv);
                viewHolder.TitleTV = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.titletv);
                viewHolder.MusicIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.musicImage);
                //
                viewHolder.TitleTV.setText(artist);
                viewHolder.ArtistTV.setText(title);
                viewHolder.MusicIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
                //
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

                return convertView;

            default:
                break;
            }

            viewHolder = new songListWidgetHolder();
            viewHolder.ArtistTV = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.artisttv);
            viewHolder.TitleTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titletv);
            viewHolder.MusicIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.musicImage);
            viewHolder.NewMusicTV = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.newmusicTV);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
    } else {
        viewHolder = (songListWidgetHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (musicList.size() > 0 && musicList != null){
    final String _title = musicList.get(position).getTitle();
    title = AppUtils.ShortText(_title, 7);
    final String _artist = musicList.get(position).getArtist();
    artist = AppUtils.ShortText(_artist, 5);
    viewHolder.TitleTV.setText(title);
    viewHolder.ArtistTV.setText(artist);
    viewHolder.MusicIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
    Date musicModifiedDate = musicList.get(position)
            .getDatemodified();
    Date systemDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    if (musicModifiedDate != null)
        if (AppUtils.GetDateDifference(systemDate, musicModifiedDate)) {
            viewHolder.NewMusicTV.setText("New");
        }

    AnimationManager.StartAnimation(Act, AnimationManager.PUSH_UP_IN_ANIMATION, convertView,1000);
    }
    return convertView;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// We used it to Search songs in our musicList arraylist
    public Filter getFilter(final int keySearch) {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                // final CarouselDataItem[] musicList;
                final ArrayList<music> results = new ArrayList<music>();
                //
                if (_musicList == null)
                    _musicList = musicList;
                // check if constraint is not null
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // check if the music List have data
                    if (_musicList != null && _musicList.size() > 0) {
                        // loop to the arraylist of music list
                        for (final music _music : _musicList) {
                            // check if the music object is equals to the
                            // constraint character
                            switch (keySearch) {
                            case SEARCH_TITLE:
                                if (searchTitle(_music, constraint.toString()))
                                    results.add(_music);
                                break;
                            case SEARCH_ARTIST:
                                if (searchArtist(_music, constraint.toString()))
                                    results.add(_music);
                                break;
                            case SEARCH_KARAOKENUMBER:
                                if (searchKaraokeNumber(_music,
                                        constraint.toString()))
                                    results.add(_music);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                            }
                            //
                        }
                    }
                    // set results of the filter search in oReturn
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                // return the results
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                musicList = (ArrayList<music>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

private boolean searchTitle(music song, String title) {
    String _title = song.getTitle().toLowerCase();
    return _title.startsWith(title.toLowerCase());
}

private boolean searchArtist(music song, String artist) {
    String _artist = song.getArtist().toLowerCase();
    return _artist.startsWith(artist.toLowerCase());
}

private boolean searchKaraokeNumber(music song, String karaokenum) {
    String _karaokenum = song.getMusicrefID();
    return _karaokenum.contains(karaokenum);
}
```